# Javascript defineProperty

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

When using:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj,prop,desc){
    get: function(){...
    set: function(){...
}
```

Does the getter/setter apply to `obj[prop]` or does it act on `obj` no matter what property is specified?

I am asking because I'm trying to setup some data binding based on a nested object like:

```
obj[propA] = {propB:'seomthing',propC:'somethingElse'}
```

and when I do something like this:

```js
var obj = {value:{propA:'testA',propB:'testB'}};

Object.defineProperty(obj.value,'propA',{
    get: function(){return this.value;},
    set: function(newValue){this.value=newValue;console.log('propA: ',newValue);}
});

console.log(obj.value.propA);

obj.value.propA = 'testA';

Object.defineProperty(obj.value,'propB',{
    get: function(){return this.value;},
    set: function(newValue){this.value=newValue;console.log('propB: ',newValue);}
});

console.log(obj.value.propB);

obj.value.propB = 'testB';

console.log('propA: ',obj.value.propA,' --propB: ',obj.value.propB);
```

the getter assigns the value to ALL the properties set by `defineProperty` within the object.

If this is the correct functionality, is there a way to have the getter/setter work only on the property defined such that in the fiddle above, propA would yield testA and propB would yield testB?

Comment: Read the docs, man. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The getter and setter only apply to the named property, but `this` inside each one refers to the object whose property it is (you don’t have to have a backing variable for every property).

In your example, you’re always reading and modifying `obj.value.value`. You can create a different variable for each one by wrapping each in an IIFE, for example:

```
(function () {
    var value;

    Object.defineProperty(obj.value, 'propA', {
        get: function () { return value; },
        set: function (newValue) { value = newValue; },
    });
})();
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwhbadqk/2/)

Comment: Oh geez...I figured this would be something I was completely overlooking. Thanks bunches minitech!

Comment: So that makes 'value' a keyword as well?

Comment: @MagicLasso: I’m not sure what you mean by “keyword” – it’s a variable.

Comment: I had arbitrarily set a var value already just before calling ...defineProperty which allowed removing 'this' keyword to make the whole script work. Its inconsequential but this did fix my issue. thanks again

Comment: @MagicLasso: It’s just a variable declaration having the anonymous function as a scope. That’s why the function’s there – to keep `value` inside and prevent anything else from changing it.